# Erro ao relacionar duas tabelas no banco

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Estou com um projeto web em java, no qual estou mapeando torres e patchpanels, onde uma torre tem varios patchs e um patch tem apenas uma torre vinculado a ele. Esse relacionamento esta tudo ok, agora o relacionamento de portas com patch, onde um patch tem varias portas e uma porta tem apenas um patch vinculado a ele esta dando erro. Ao cadastrar novo patch e adicionar equipamentos as portas ele salva os equipamentos mas nao vincula a qual patch panel ele esta vinculado. Como podem ver abaixo, onde descrição seria o equipamento conectado a porta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu model patch panel: `package models;

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.data.validation.Unique;
import play.db.jpa.Model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
@Entity
public class Patchpanel extends Model {

@Required
public String nome;
@Required
public String mac;
@Required
@Unique
public String ip;
@Required
public String numPortas;

@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="patchpanels")
public List<Porta> portas;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="torre_id")
public Torre torre;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

public Patchpanel() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
}
}
```

`
meu model portas:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Porta extends Model {

@Required
public String descricao;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

@ManyToOne
public Patchpanel patchpanels;

public Porta() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
}
}
```

Meu controlador patchpanels onde sao salvos os patch:

```
public static void salvarPatchpanel(@Valid Patchpanel patchpanel, List<String> portas) {

    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        params.flash();
        validation.keep();
        formPatchpanel();
    }

    for (String porta : portas) {
        patchpanel.portas = new ArrayList<Porta>();
        Porta p = new Porta();
        p.descricao = porta;
        patchpanel.portas.add(p);
        patchpanel.save();
    }
    String mensagem = "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!";
    flash.success(mensagem);
    //patchpanel.save();
    listagemPatchpanel(null);

}
```

Comment: Tem alguma coisa no log? Ou ele apenas salva como null?

Comment: Nada no log, apenas salva como Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não está faltando um `@JoinColumn(name="NOME_DA_COLUNA")` neste código?

```
@ManyToOne
public Patchpanel patchpanels;
```